# Python TypeHint for Covariant Callable Argument?

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

an interesting TypeHint conundrum I'm facing at the moment surrounding TypeVars (at least I believe this is the tool I should be using in some capacity). I have a class and a subclass of it (and then many more subclasses of both Base and Sub).

```
class Base:
    ...


class Sub(Base):
    ...
```

I have a function that should take a callable of any subclass of `Base` and return a fixed object type (let's say int for convenience). I have this guy defined as such (note the TypeHint on `f` here is not what I want, just intro example):

```
def accepts_any_base_callable(f: Callable[[Base], int]):  # <- This Callable sig is not what I want
    ...
```

I have a different function which produces callables of this nature that are specifically of type `Sub` and subclasses of `Sub`, which I could type as:

```
def produce_sub_callables() -> Callable[[Sub], int]:
    ...
```

This is where my problem starts:

```
accepts_any_base_callable(produce_sub_callables())
```

This obviously doens't work due to Callable having contravariant arguments. I understand how this concept works and it is not my problem. My problem is that I don't need the Callable to work for all given `Base` - I just want a TypeHint that means the arg matches a `Base` or a subclass.

So I tried using some bounded TypeVars - this is closer in spirit to what I want:

```
B = TypeVar('B', bound=Base)
S = TypeVar('S', bound=Sub)


def accepts_any_base_callable(c: Callable[[B], int]):
    ...


def produce_sub_callable() -> Callable[[S], int]:
    ...


accepts_any_base_callable(produce_sub_callable())
```

But this last line gives me a warning in PyCharm:
`Expected type '(Any) -> int' (matched generic type '(B) -> int'), got '(S) -> int' instead`. Note that this isn't actually related to type variance in any way.

Is there some way to set up my TypeVars and TypeHints here in such a way that that last line of code doesn't produce warnings? Realistically I don't think it really matters that `Sub` is a subclass of `Base` - I would just like to have *some* way of describing `produce_sub_callables` that shows it produces `Sub` callables

Comment: I get no errors reported when I run mypy on this (after adding an appropriate `return` statement to `produce_sub_callable`). Dunno about PyCharm.

Comment: Ah ok, so possibly a PyCharm related problem then. I know I've had some issues with them registering things like virtual subclasses in their static checking, so definitely possible.

Comment: Have you tried using the concrete type for `produce_sub_callable`? (aka return `Callable[[Sub], int]` instead of `Callable[[S], int]`) I think PyCharm is probably confused because it cannot bind `B` nor `S`.